# Disable console.assert in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an Android WebView that loads .js files containing several `console.assert(...)` calls.

I would like to disable all `console.assert` calls when running those scripts in the Android WebView.
It is possible to do so? Could we imagine to do so only in certain build configuration/flavors?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: you can follow this link , hope you get some idea :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222006/how-to-extend-javascript-console-in-webview-to-match-consolemessage-messageleve

Comment: thanks for the link. It talks about catching and redirecting console messages, which is usually a great think. But here, what I am looking for is a way to _disable_ completely the console.assert(). Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried , also not worked on it : i think if there is console message then you should have to return false .Try this but don't know it's work or not

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
{
   @Override
   public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
      Log.d("TAG", cm.message() + " at " + cm.sourceId() + ":" + cm.lineNumber());
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: This solution does intercept the assert messages, but it does not prevent them from being evaluated, executed and sent. This is what I am looking for. Maybe a workaround would be to use a custom function `myAssert()` instead of `console.assert()`, and override it to make it dummy in some build flavors.